# PyCharm "Can't get remote credentials for deployment server"

Tags: pycharm, admin, jetbrains-ide

After config remote interpreter and deployment I got the following error when PyCharm trying to install libs from `requirements.txt`

> Can't get remote credentials for deployment server

Comment: OS used? If Linux/Mac (especially Linux), it must be trying to use your Keychain to store and access login info .. and it fails (that's the first thing that comes into my mind from your description). On Linux it could be because of missing support library for your Keychain. Try changing password storage to KeePass, it works good on all platforms.

Comment: deployment to linux from windows

Comment: So you are on Windows (the OS where IDE is running). Is that the latest IDE version (2018.3.x)? Please check `idea.log` for possible exceptions/hints (`Help | Show Log in Explorer`), anything interesting there? (share the file if you can)

Comment: yes 2018.3.2  Build #PY-183.4886.43

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ra-coder/238da0d7201af0e47193417ead611908

Comment: So .. from the log .. it happens when "Performing background update of skeletons for SDK Remote Python 3.6.7". I'm not a PyCharm or Python user .. but that interpreter .. is that IDE-wide entry (available for every project) or a project-specific one? I'm referring to this dev comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30927#focus=streamItem-27-2970117.0-0. Other than that -- please check and comment in one of these tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY?q=%22get%20remote%20credentials%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it happen to be wrong configuration of remote interpretor, i configured it once again and all works

Comment: Next time, could please tell us, what was the solution?

Comment: Ryabchenko Alexander Can you please post the solution that worked for you?

Answer (score 37):

I had the same problem. I configured first a deployment server and then the remote interpreter using the same deployment server config. I was asked if I want to either create a copy or move the configuration from the project level to the IDE level. I moved it.

The problem is that the credentials for the server are only available on the project level. To solve it I had to:

- go back to the Deployment Configuration
- click on these "..." till I reached the "SSH Configurations"
- Unchecked the "Visible only for this project" checkbox

[image]

Comment: This is somewhat strange, but it worked for me to remove the "Visible only for this project" flag on the `Deployment configuration` (!)

Comment: Same for me. However, unchecked both. But thanks for the hint. Maybe if I had read every page of the documentation, with a bit of luck I could have known it

Comment: the mouse in the image trolled me before the morning coffee!

Comment: Thanks. confirm this method fixed my issue.

Answer (score 12):

I'm using SSH to achieve my Interpreter and encountered sameerror. I tried solutions above, but all in vain.

My solution is, make sure you choose the **SSH** when you configure your Interpreter. (When I choose **Deployment configuration** as default, error comes)[image]

Then, configure your deployment in the **Tools**. [image]

Another solution is remove your current Python Interpreter and setup a new one. This also works for me.

Comment: This was the only solution I could get to reliably work, thanks!

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me too, but tired of resetting everytime this happens. Does anyone know reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

For me, remove the debug configuration and create a new one worked

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue 2 ways:

- the SSH configuration was configured correctly, but the python interpreter was using the wrong interpreter (that was deleted previously).

  - **Solution:** go to the interpreter settings and re-select your **"deployment configuration"**.
    [image: PyCharm's "Configure Remote Python Interpreter" window]
- The SSH configuration was scoped to the project. Remote Interpreters cannot use deployments which in turn use **project-specific configuration** (<kbd>Visible only for this project</kbd> is checked). SSH configuration must be saved in the **IDE settings**, so you should uncheck this option. This is the same as [chickahoona's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66329318/7365866).

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I deleted my project and created and configured it again. My configuration is related to an ssh interpreter and a remote deployment. So even if I have configurated as right, this error appears.

So, the solution was not only to configure it right but to **remove** the old remote interpreter as well.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. What I did was reconfigure the interpreter using ssh again. Everything worked then.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I configured many interpreters in Pycharm for various projects. I tried all the probable solutions (listed in this post) but was unsuccessful, so I [Deleted](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/python-interpreters.html#available) all the interpreters and restarted Pycharm. Then I [reconfigured](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html#ssh) the remote interpreter, and it now work fine.